# Find the last inserted row that matches a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the last inserted row that matches a query (ie, find the row that has the largest id among the matching rows.)

for instance, suppose the following query matches 3 rows. with ids, 1,2,and 3. I want to get only the row with id 3.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `mail` = 'someone@example.com'
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE `mail` = 'someone@example.com'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE `mail` = 'someone@example.com'
AND id=
(
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl 
    WHERE `mail` = 'someone@example.com'
);
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39ab6/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Order By`. You sort your result with `Id` values in decreasing order (that way, you would have maximum ID at the top, in this case 3) and then just limit your result with value 1. That would give you only one row, with max ID. So,

here goes the query:

```
SELECT * FROM *YourTableName* where mail = '*YourMail*'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```